# Adding frame over video in iphone - objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, templates, video, frame

I am developing an application where the user has the feature to add frames to the video being captured or to the existing video from the library.
This frames are custom design like the ones in news channel, where the subtitle of the video comes with the name of reporter and so on..
for example
The "Live" tag in the top left of the video..
Can anyone guide me the way how shall I accomplish this, atleast can give me a hint what I can use in this project..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a video being captured, have a look at the `cameraOverlayView` property of the `UIImagePickerController`.